# How to position a car in image processing (computer vision)?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to locate a car (front center point x,y) using a high resolution single camera. The camera setup is fixed at 1-2m high, and tilted around 25 degrees. The camera can provide images in where the front side of the car is visible. The intrinsic and extrinsic parameters are known.

So far, I tried to detect the headlights and number plates. Issues... Headlights are not detected as blobs all the time. The shape of the headlights are changing depending on the distance. Also, the number plate is not visible in the dark.

Is there a robust algorithm to detect a car? or to detect headlights? or detect number plate?How could I proceed?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Are you detecting the same car everytime? If yes, then presumably the appearance remains consistent. Rather than detect and recognise blobs and shapes, you may be better off using scale and rotation invariant features combined with a machine learning algorithm. Look into the [SIFT](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/iccv99.pdf) and [SURF](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/eccv06.pdf) feature descriptors. For easy experimentation, use OpenCV's implementation of feature description and matching. Take a look at [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was too fast. No, not the same car everytime. I assumed that the same car everytime. Later, I used Oriented Brief, Brief, commercial SIFT and SURF. Unfortunately, the result was very bad under bad lightning condition. I gave up using descriptors. I need a solution which works during the day and night.  Let us assume that the illumination is good enough and SIFT or SURF works well. How would I combine it with machine learning?

Comment: With SIFT and SURF, you may be able to get away without the need for a classifier. What you will need to do is, take a few snapshots of the place without any car at different times of the day, and also take a few snapshots each of every car that may be parked there at different times of the day. Then perform feature matching between your test image and all of these snapshots. The snapshot that provides the highest number of feature matches is likely to be the correct match. This way, you wouldn't build a single model with machine learning, but hedge your bets with multiple models.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy problem because of the change in the scale and point of view. Ideally, you would need a collection of training images with the car seen from different points of view to match later some of them to your input image. Then, you need local features (SIFT, SURF) or some classifier to decide on the match.

On the other hand, if you are tracking the same car all the time, check out the [MeanShift algorithm](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cv-meanshift). The problem is you need an initial position to carry on with the tracking.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is not easy problem, especially due to the lightning changes. There is almost no features if the car is far and the image is a little bit dark. I start playing exposure time but still could not get any results so far.

Comment: The computer vision is not mature enough to solve this problem? What do you think?

Comment: It is mature, but not enough to say that there is an out-of-the-box tool to recognize any object under any circumstance. The problem you want to solve is named "category recognition" or "object classification". There is a lot of literature about. Search these terms, and check out solutions based on part-based models (e.g. Fergus et al. 2007) or bags of words (e.g. Nister et al. 2006), for example. Apart from the detection/recognition of the car, obtaining its position in the 3D space, if you need it in addition to the image, is again another problem.